Recalculating Normals
I am trying to recalculate the normals for my model, however, the options appear to be missing. After a quick Google, I found a tutorial saying use the "mesh" menu in edit mode: mesh > normals > recalculate outside. For me, the mesh menu is missing in edit mode. I also tried using keyboard shortcuts "shift + N", in the preferences it states this is the shortcut to recalculate, but when I use it, it shows a "Recalculate Roll" menu that does not have the recalculate outside option anywhere. Is there a way to restore the mesh menu in edit mode?
I am using Blender 2.83, due to working with some older plugins, I can't use a newer version.


You have selected your armature, not your mesh object (example: Recalculate Roll is for the armature's bones), switch back to Object mode, select the mesh object and switch to Edit mode.

Thank you so much!, I'm fairly new to blender and this was driving me nuts.
